# how to add nested array of object in java script?

Tags: arrays, object, nested, addition

I want add personal Array of object in bikash.
Here's my code.. please Help me..!!!

```
const people=[{
 bikash:[{
    name:'Bikash',
    surName:'Khadka',
    address:'Chabahil',
  }],
}]

people[0].bikash.push(personal[{
  occupation: 'insteuctor',
  hobbie: 'FootBall',
}])
console.log(people);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

people is defined as const, change it to let

```
let people=[{bikash:[{ name:'Bikash', surName:'Khadka', address:'Chabahil'}]}];
people[0].bikash[0].personal = [{ occupation: 'insteuctor', hobbie: 'FootBall'}];
```